# Unable to set image background image

Tags: javascript, html, background-image

Hello all I am working in html5 and JavaScript and I am stuck in a problem

So I have div which I am dynamically appending like this

```
container.append('<div id=del_' + container_id + ' style = " background-image: url(' + "del_btn.png" + ') no-repeat center center;"/>');
```

My div is created but I am unable to see the background image can any one guide me what is the mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Incorrect path? Where is your image in file system? Or, maybe, your div is zero-width / zero-height?

Comment: it in same folder where i have kept my js file

Comment: Try setting absolute path (for testing purposes)

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits it working with absolute path.

Comment: but how to make it work with relative path

Comment: If it works with absolute path, you need to place your image in correct location in file system to use relative path. That's kinda' obvious. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that it is in the same folder as the javacript files.

If for example your JS files reside in a different folder than the html page, say `scripts`

you would need to modify the image path too to something like `'scripts/del_btn.png'`

Comment: okay got it now.Actually I have my *.js file and images in JS folder and my html is outside it.So in my file.js i have to give path w.r.t html.thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the path to the image. As it is in your example the image needs to be in the same folder as the html. If you have it in a subfolder to the web site root, say 'scripts', the path should be `/scripts/del_btn.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
container.append('<div id=del_' + container_id + ' style = " background-image: url(\'del_btn.png\') no-repeat center center;"/>');
```

You dont require `+` here

**EDIT** escaped '

Answer (score 0):

use `background` instead of `background-image`, because `background-image` only accepts image url as value.

```
container.append('<div id=del_' + container_id + ' style = " background: url(' + "del_btn.png" + ') no-repeat center center;"/>');
```

and set css for the div

```
display: block;
width:  100px; /* for example */
height: 100px; /* for example */
```

Comment: see a sample that works http://jsfiddle.net/3sVMR/ . you have to give width and height or there should be some content inside  that div. If you are giving percentage width and height then it's parent element should have valid width and height.